# How to end a dialog mfc application from CDialog::OnInitDialog or immediately after this function ends?

Tags: mfc, initialization, cdialog

In one case of my application, I want to end the application in the dialog's OnInitDialog or immediately after this function. Is there any way to do it?

I tried using windows messages – in OnInitDialog calling SendMessage and in the handler of the sent message calling OnClose – but it didn't do what I intended since the dialog still appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PostQuitMessage(0)` in the `WM_INITDIALOG` handler body will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate the user clicking the `X` in the corner of the dialog by sending a `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message:

```
PostMessage(WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution:

```
    CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()
    {
       if( "My Condition is invalid" )
       {
         EndDialog(-1);
         return FALSE;
       }
    }
```

You have to do "return FALSE" juste after EndDialog because as you can read in the  [Microsoft documentation CDialog(classe)](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class?view=msvc-170#enddialog), EndDialog doesn't close the dialog immediately, but generates a notification which when handled by Microsoft has to effect to end the dialog.